# Invalid value in tensor used for shape: -1879048192

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I  try to reshape a tensor with high dimension, it causes the error as follows:

```
Invalid value in tensor used for shape: -1879048192
```

The code is : `tf.reshape(scores, shape=[-1, nb_features*nb_features])`, where scores is a matrix whose shape is 45192*45192 and nb_features is 45192.

WHy I get this error? Is the dimension too high?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue, it's due to the high dimension. Did you find a solution, please?